# How does this last step in Shor's algorithm work?

Tags: quantum-computing, number-theory

Page 854 of The Nature of Computation states the following (This discussion has made the simplifying assumption that $M/r$ is an integer):

> If each of the observations gives us a random harmonic, how long does it take to learn the fundamental frequency? Suppose we observe the frequencies $k_1 = b_1 M/r$, $k_2 = b_2 M/r$, and so on. As soon as the $b_i$ are relatively prime, i.e., $\gcd(b_1, b_2,...) = 1$, then $\gcd(k_1, k_2,...) = M/r$. With constant probability even the first two observations suffice, since as Problem 10.26 shows, $b_1$ and $b_2$ are mutually prime with probability $6/\pi^2$ when $r$ is large. Thus we can determine $M/r$ from a constant number of observations on average, and we simply divide $M$ by $M/r$ to obtain $r$.

But how can we figure out that we've reached the point that the $b_i$ are mutually prime? This procedure reads to me as if there was a deterministic way of detecting that and it was only the number of necessary observations that was random.